# Apache Mod Rewrite Rule with ? like Google i.e. ?hl=en

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a working *RewriteRule*:

`RewriteRule ^category/?(.*)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)$ category.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&id=$2&paginate=$3&sort=$4&page=$5 [L]`

Processed *URL* looks like:

`www.mysite.com/category/hockey/10/18/recent-3`

Now I want my *URL* to look like:

`www.mysite.com/category/hockey?id=10&paginate=18&sort=recent-3`

I have tried:

`RewriteRule ^category/?(.*)?id=([0-9]+)&paginate=([0-9]+)&sort=([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)$ category.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&id=$2&paginate=$3&sort=$4&page=$5 [L]`

but I couldn't make it work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the `?` in the URL) in a `RewriteRule`. You have to do it against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable and backreference using the `%`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)&paginate=([0-9]+)&sort=([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^category/?(.*) category.php?id=%1&paginate=%2&sort=%3&page=%4 [L]
```

Comment: Ahh, that's why! :) Jon, thank you for your explanation and your answer! It worked like expected!